# How to group by Date and Hour :00:00 in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I want to create hourly report and this query is running perfectly.

```
SELECT 
    FORMAT(PingLogDate,'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:00:00') AS CalculatedTime, 
    COUNT(PingLogID) AS PingCount
FROM
    tbl_PingLog
GROUP BY 
    FORMAT(PingLogDate,'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:00:00')
ORDER BY 
    FORMAT(PingLogDate,'yyyy-MM-dd-HH:00:00')
```

But I'm supporting SQL Server 2008 and `Format` is new in SQL Server 2012, so I tried this code

```
SELECT 
    CAST(PingLogDate AS date) AS CalculatedDate, 
    DATEPART(hour, PingLogDate) AS CalculatedTime, 
    COUNT(PingLogID) AS PingCount
FROM
    tbl_PingLog
GROUP BY 
    CAST(PingLogDate AS date), DATEPART(hour, PingLogDate)
ORDER BY 
    CAST(PingLogDate AS date), DATEPART(hour, PingLogDate)
```

The problem is don't want to 2 column for date and hour for example

First query's result is

```
CalculatedTime      | PingCount
--------------------+-----------
2017-11-07-12:00:00 | 359
2017-11-07-13:00:00 | 359
2017-11-07-14:00:00 | 350
```

Second query's result is

```
CalculatedDate |CalculatedTime | PingCount
---------------+---------------+----------
2017-11-07     |12             | 359
2017-11-07     |13             | 359
2017-11-07     |14             | 350
```

I don't want second one. I want first one. How to do that with SQL Server 2008 supported tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CONVERT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(v=sql.100).aspx) to transform the `datetime` column to `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss(24h)` format and then replace the space with `-`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), PingLogDate, 120), ' ', '-') AS CalculatedTime, 
       COUNT(PingLogID) AS PingCount
FROM tbl_PingLog
GROUP BY REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), PingLogDate, 120), ' ', '-')
ORDER BY REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), PingLogDate, 120), ' ', '-')
```

Comment: The problem is it is give me all ping (every 10 sec) it is not what i want. Your output is  
CalculatedTime          | PingCount
2017-11-07-12:20:03  | 1
2017-11-07-12:20:13  | 1 
This is now what i want

Answer (score 0):

Try this method with convert and concatenation of hours.
This will give you ping count for each hour and datetime format same as you got using **FORMAT** method in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), date_field, 120),' ','-') + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HOUR, date_field)), 2) + ':00:00' as CalculatedTime,
COUNT(PingLogID) AS PingCount
FROM tbl_PingLog
GROUP BY REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), date_field, 120),' ','-') + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HOUR, date_field)), 2) + ':00:00'
ORDER BY REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), date_field, 120),' ','-') + '-' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(HOUR, date_field)), 2) + ':00:00'
```

Comment: Though it's just a modified version of answer from @gotqn :P

Comment: Yeah it's work well but i don't want to go out  of date/datetime format . I can do it at c# side using string format. It is not what i exactly want. But its works thanks.

Comment: @BMErEr Always mark answered or up-vote if someone answers your question.

Comment: I want to up but i can't because of my reputation but i can't give mark because this is not what i exactly want

Comment: I'm afraid this is all you get if you are on SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of other solutions

```
SELECT 
    replace(convert(varchar(13),PingLogDate,120),' ','-')+':00:00'  AS CalculatedTime, 
    COUNT(PingLogID) AS PingCount
FROM
    tbl_PingLog
GROUP BY 
    convert(varchar(13),PingLogDate,120)
ORDER BY CalculatedTime
```

Comment: as i told Nitin_g3  "i don't want to go out of date/datetime format . I can do it at c# side using string format. It is not what i exactly want. "

Comment: Look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql. Return types of **Format** are **nvarchar** and **null**. Even your first solution is not returning datetime. And yyyy-MM-dd-HH:00:00 is not valid datetime format. If you want it to be datetime you should convert it back to datetime. Like cast(convert(varchar(13),b_datetime,120)+':00:00' as datetime)

Answer (score 0):

what about using this easy statement in your code?

```
declare @date datetime = getdate()
select DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @date), 0)
```

result will be like `2017-11-25 00:00:00.000`

This is the best way to trim the time from the `datetime` field

Comment: I don't want to trim time from datetime. But if I want to do that i will do like that cast(mydate as date)